# Remove duplicates from multiple column so that output will be unique in excel

Tags: excel

I have these 2 coulmn:

```
Column 1    Column 2
A              E
B              F
C              B
D              A
               G
```

I need to compare the two columns so the output must be:

```
Column 3
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

Comment: This is a programmers forum, so I assume you are programming in Excel: Check the SQL keyword distinct

Comment: You can use Excel's inbuilt feature to [remove duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2). Is there something specific that you want to do via VBA? In that case, have you scripted anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well if your data is in columns A and B:

```
| A     |  B    |
|---    |----   |
| A     | E     |
| B     | F     |
| C     | B     |
| D     | A     |
| G     |       |
```

You can use this one that will throw `#N/A` once you hit the limit and requires first row to have some unique text:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$1:$A$4),0)),INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$1:$B$5),0)))
```

And it is an array formula that needs to be applied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Result it column `D`:

```
| D         |
|--------   |
| Unique    |
| A         |
| B         |
| C         |
| D         |
| E         |
| F         |
| G         |
| #N/A      |
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a formula like this one starting in Cell C2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$5),,),)),IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$B$2:$B$6),,),)),""))
```

This is a regular (non-array) formula.

Note that althought the result looks sorted, there is no sorting, it is reported in the order that the values are encountered.[image: Columns 1, 2, and 3]

I know this wasn't part of the request, but since I mentioned it, if we wanted the list sorted despite the order of the original columns, I think this formula entered into C2 and copied down would work as an array formula entered with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$6, SMALL(IF(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$B$6)+ISBLANK($A$2:$B$6)=0, COUNTIF($A$2:$B$6, "<"&$A$2:$B$6)+1, ""), 1)=IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$B$6), "", COUNTIF($A$2:$B$6, "<"&$A$2:$B$6)+1), ROW($A$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$B$6))+1), 1), MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$B$6)+ISBLANK($A$2:$B$6)>0, "", COUNTIF($A$2:$B$6, "<"&$A$2:$B$6)+1)), INDEX(IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$B$6), "", COUNTIF($A$2:$B$6, "<"&$A$2:$B$6)+1), SMALL(IF(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$B$6)+ISBLANK($A$2:$B$6)=0, COUNTIF($A$2:$B$6, "<"&$A$2:$B$6)+1, ""), 1)=IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$B$6), "", COUNTIF($A$2:$B$6, "<"&$A$2:$B$6)+1), ROW($A$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$B$6))+1), 1), , 1), 0), 1),"")
```

See the following with a modified set of original values.  I referenced the input columns as a range which makes it a bit complicated since I had to remove blank values.

[image]